# Volume of a solid with specific cross sections

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, volume

We can use definite integrals to find volume of a solid with specific cross sections on the interval.

If the cross section is perpendicular to $x$-axis and its  area is a function of $x$, say $A(x)$, then the volume $V$ of the solid on $[a, b]$ can be found using the formula

$V = \int_a^b A(x)dx$

Now in the proof of lecture notes it is assumed that all that cross sections are into the other[image: like this] like this(meaning they are not disjoint and they can't partially intersect)

For example take ellipsoid.

I understand why this is assumed because we are proving using darboux sums.But question is can you first bring some counterexample that this method does not work?And if I want to calculate volume with this method then how to check that all cross sections are into the other.Thank you.

Comment: You might be interested in Cavalieri's principle, which may be formally proven with Fubini's theorem

Comment: @FShrike I read about Cavalieri's principle but can you please explain how it can solve my question?

Comment: I'll type up a little explanation as soon as I understand what you mean by "the cross sections are not disjoint and can't partially intersect". The cross sections are surely disjoint, since they are taken at different $x$-slices

Comment: @FShrike Sorry.When you take x-slices and then project them onto the plane that is perpendicular to the x-axis then then one will be onto the other.For example for ellipsoid  if you take two x-slices you get ellipses and if you project them onto the plane perpendicular to x-axis you'll get one ellipse is into the other.Is now more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}$[Cavalieri's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalieri%27s_principle) is an intuitive statement relating the volumes of two solids if they have the same cross-sectional areas for every possible cross-section. An informal justification for $V=\int_a^bA(x)\d x$ is that the collection of cross-sections summed over $[a,b]$ will lead to the same volume, by Cavalieri's principle, so long as we account for *every* cross-section; thus taking limits leads to the integral from a Riemann sum. At no point do we have any requirements on the geometry of the solid other than it must have a meaningful volume, and the area function should be Riemann-integrable over $[a,b]$. The projections of the cross sections can theoretically be disjoint, but this would just  lead to a rather bizarre shape that would be difficult to call a solid, but if there were finitely many places where the cross sections are disjoint you could think about the sum of a finite collection of "normal" solids. If there were infinitely many discontinuities in this sense, the solid might not be "measurable" and the volume would be ill-defined by most people's standards.

This is not really a "proof" however.

You may have heard of measure theory, a more general theory of integration. Henri Lebesgue developed the theory of the Lebesgue measure, $\mu$, on $\Bbb R^n$, which *is the natural area/volume*: the measure of a box is the product of its side lengths, and it is translationally invariant, and scales under linear maps by the determinant, etc. and if you study its construction a little more you'll see that $\mu(S)$ is truly the "volume" of $S\subset\Bbb R^n$ in its most natural sense. We can find the measure of a set by integrating along its characteristic function; $\chi_S$ is the function for which $\chi_S(x)=1$ if $x\in S$, and $\chi_S(x)=0$ otherwise:

$$\text{Volume of $S$}=\mu(S)=\int_{\Bbb R^n}\chi_S\d\mu=\int_{S}1\d\mu$$

This is just like how $b-a=\int_a^b1\d x$, the "volume" of a line in one-dimensional space, and is just a more general way of expressing this. Hopefully this is making sense, even if you've not studied measure theory.

A very important and famous theorem from measure theory is [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem), one corollary of which is that I can split an integral over $\Bbb R^n$ into an integral over $\Bbb R^{n-1}$ and $\Bbb R$. This theorem is what powers the rigorous "reason" why these integrations work (but do think about how you want "volume" to be *defined* - under a different definition, i.e. a different measure, this might not work - Lebesgue's measure is just the "natural" measure of volume). From here on out I'll take $\Bbb R^3$ and split into $\Bbb R^2$ and $\Bbb R$ to give a direct analogy to your cross-sectional area problem.

So I can do this (where $\mu_2,\mu_1$ are two and one-dimensional measures, i.e. area and line length, or area and Riemann's "$\d x$"):

$$\begin{align}\text{Volume of $S$}=\mu(S)&=\int_{\Bbb R^3}\chi_S(x,y,z)\d\mu\\&=\int_{\Bbb R}\left(\int_{\Bbb R^2}\chi_S(x,y,z)\d\mu_2(y,z)\right)\d\mu_1(x)\\&=\int_{\Bbb R}A(x)\d x\\&=\int_a^b A(x)\d x\end{align}$$

Where $A(x)$ is $\int_{\Bbb R^2}\chi_S(x,y,z)\d\mu_2(y,z)$, i.e. the *area* (because $\mu_2,\Bbb R^2$) of the $2$-D $x$-slice of $S$, the cross-sectional area.

The measure theory there is just a very elegant way to justify it, but you don't need to know it all to make sense of this. It is just a fact (Fubini) that I can split volume integrals into $1$-D integrals of area and this is all justified and correlates to the intuitive definitions of area and volume - a powerful extension of $\int_a^b 1\d x=b-a$. Oh, and these fancy $\mu$-integrals are actually the same as Riemann integrals when the Riemann integral exists, but you can take a $\mu$-integral more often - here, we just need that $S$ is "measurable" - all this means is that it's a well-behaved patch of space; e.g. if I move it around, its volume won't change (although this is not the only requirement). Surprisingly, not all sets are measurable - see the [Banach-Tarski paradox: Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Tarski_paradox), [Banach-Tarski paradox: entertaining VSauce video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s86-Z-CbaHA) and the [Vitali set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set) for more.

To re-iterate, this is only a proof in the sense that it shows that the natural definition of volume ($\mu$) can be related to these cross-sectional integrals. Had you used a different measure which splits differently, or a different notion of volume, or if you harbour objections to Lebesgue's measure being natural, then you can refute the above. This is just "the" definition that is overwhelmingly used.

About the torus:

Let $r,R$ be the minor and major radii, and put $a=R+r$, $b=R-r$. Then $a$ is the maximum distance from a point to the centre, and $b$ is the minimum. The area of an ellipse is $\pi\alpha\beta$, where $\alpha,\beta$ are the semi-minor/major axes. I will split the torus into two sections; the section where the cross-section is solid, and the inner section where there is a gap. In the image I provide I call these sections $A_1,A_2$. In $A_1$, if we consider $x$ to be the distance to the centre point, the semi-major axis of the cross-sectional ellipse about that point is given by pythagoras: $a^2=x^2+\alpha^2,\,\alpha=\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$. The semi-minor axis is always $r$ by construction of the torus ($r$ is how much the circular shape pokes up). Then, in $A_1$, $A(x)=\pi r\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$.

In the section $A_2$, the cross-section falls into two disjoint ellipses of equal area. The semi-minor axis is still $r$ for both, and the semi-major axis is given by (as explained geometrically in the image, taking $\alpha$ as the difference of the two horizontals) $\sqrt{a^2-x^2}-\sqrt{b^2-x^2}$. Then $A(x)=\pi r(\sqrt{a^2-x^2}-\sqrt{b^2-x^2})$ in this region.

Altogether:

$$\begin{align}V=\int_{-a}^aA(x)\d x&=\underset{A_1}{\underbrace{\int_{-a}^{-b}A(x)\d x+\int_b^aA(x)\d x}}+\underset{A_2}{\underbrace{\int_{-b}^bA(x)\d x}}\\&=2\pi r\int_b^a\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\d x+2\pi r\int_0^b\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\d x-2\pi r\int_0^b\sqrt{b^2-x^2}\d x\\&=2\pi r\left(\int_0^a\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\d x-\int_0^b\sqrt{b^2-x^2}\d x\right)\\&=2\pi r\left(a^2\color{red}{\int_0^1\sqrt{1-x^2}\d x}-b^2\color{red}{\int_0^1\sqrt{1-x^2}\d x}\right)\\&=2\pi r(a^2-b^2)\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{4}}\\&=2\pi r\cdot\frac{\pi}{4}(a-b)(a+b)\\&=2\pi r\cdot\frac{\pi}{4}(2r)(2R)\\&=\color{red}{2\pi}\cdot\color{green}{r\pi r}\cdot\color{red}{R}\\&=(2\pi R)(\pi r^2)\end{align}$$

Which is the correct answer, and so we see that even having disjoint cross-sections is fine if the solid is nice enough!

[image: Badly drawn image]

Comment: Thank you very very much for such detailed information.One question please.If we take torus and do different x-slices and then project them I don't think all of them will be onto the other or I am wrong.

Comment: The volume of a torus is classically equal to $(\pi r^2)(2\pi R)$, where $r,R$ are the minor and major radii. Can we find this by integration? We certainly can. I will integrate around the ring of the inner circle, radius $R$, and at every point the cross sectional area will be the circle, of minor radius $r$: $$\int_0^{2\pi R}A(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^{2\pi R}(\pi r^2)\,\mathrm{d}x=(2\pi R)(\pi r^2)$$ And it works! Not all of the projections will be inside the other - there will be partial intersections - but as you can see this doesn't matter. @unit1991

Comment: We just need measurability and a well-defined $A(x)$, which we have here

Comment: A more difficult integration would be to integrate the cross sections in the way you were expecting - in a line, not a ring - but this would still work if you could figure out the geometry of the cross-sections. I might post this if I can come up with something but geometry isn't my strong suit

Comment: Thank you again very much.

Comment: I'll think more about what you said

Comment: @unit1991 I came up with a way to integrate the volume of a torus using cross sections perpendicular to the middle axis. It’s harder but it does show that even with disjoint cross sections, as we have here, it still works. Would you like me to show this?

Comment: I am not sure I'll understand but it would be very interesting for me to see how you did it @FShrike.

Comment: @unit1991 Done! If you want to know where the $\frac{\pi}{4}$ came from feel free to ask

Comment: Thank you again for this amazing work only one question.Sorry but I saw your description are you  really in the school and know already this much?I'm feeling really dumb :)

Comment: @unit1991 Please don’t feel dumb! I am really in school, but I like to think of mathematics as a time-dependent rather than age-dependent thing. Sometimes you need to have a certain age and maturity to grasp a concept, but very often someone, given enough time, can learn anything. I am no smarter than you are; I’ve just been studying mathematics for *longer*, which is completely possible even if I’m younger. I have been lucky in my life to have the chance to independently learn outside of school, and the internet for all its flaws is a beautiful place full of learning resources.

Comment: Thank you again very much it was pleasure talking to you continue like that.

Comment: @unit1991 You’re very welcome